# How do you convert a vim s: variable to a literal in a inoremap?

Tags: vim

I have a `nnoremap`, `inoremap` and a `iab` using the same string in my `.vimrc` so I wanted to factor out the string to a s:variable like this

```
let s:timestr= '%F %T %Z'
nnoremap <F5> "=strftime(s:timestr)<cr>P                                       
inoremap <F5> <C-R>=strftime(s:timestr)<cr>
iab <expr> dts strftime(s:timestr)
```

By looking at the `:help internal-variables` and more specifically to `:help script-variable` seems that script-variables `s:var` cannot be used in mappings. So I wonder if there is a way to convert the `s:timestr` to a literal when `inoremap` is processed. Right now it looks like that it tries to "resolve" the `s:timestr` every time that the mapping is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ideas:

1. You can make that `:execute` a little bit more understandable by inserting the variable via `printf()`.
2. You could make the variable a global configuration; that may come handy later, and with the customary `if exists('g:plugin_timestr')` conditional, you're on your way to a publishable plugin.
3. If this is just about refactoring and avoiding duplication, I'd use a script-local function instead:

```
function! s:Timestr()
    return '%F %T %Z'
endfunction
```

You can use that in your mappings via `<SID>Timestr()` instead of `s:timestr`.

Answer (score 0):

One option, altought ugly is to use string concatenation and `:exec`

```
let s:timestr= '%F %T %Z'
exec "iab <expr> dts strftime('" . s:timestr . "')"
```

But it arguably has a ugly syntax and makes it difficult to read.